# beautifulsoup не видит span

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

Пытаюсь написать парсер, где нужна собрать цены на продукты, программа ничего не выводит [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Присоединяюсь, сегодня был озадачен тем же вопросом. Как правильно сформировать запрос для этой функции?

Comment: Вы анализируете исходный код страницы в python, откройте исходный HTML страницы через "просмотр кода страницы" по правой кнопке мыши и увидите, что никакого класса `price--currency_KZT` там не будет. В браузере инспектор кода показывает модифицированный код после обработки DOM-дерева JavaScript'ом и он может кардинально различаться.

Answer (score 3):

Вам необходимо спускаться вниз по структуре страницы. Следующий раз добавляйте пожалуйста код не картинкой, а текстом. Вот пример рабочего кода, в котором вы увидите, что тег `"span"`, который вы ищете, вам не нужен:

```
import requests  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


link = "https://arbuz.kz/ru/astana/catalog/cat/14-napitki"

session = requests.Session()

responce = session.get(link).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce, 'html.parser')
prod = soup.find("div", "product-card-list")
articles = prod.find_all("article", "product-item product-card")
for article in articles:
    main = article.find("main", "product-card__body")
    p_price = main.find("p", "product-card__price")
    print(p_price.text.replace('  ', '').replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').replace('\r', ''))
```

Результат:

```
...
749 ₸
1596 ₸
1418 ₸
2700 ₸
1228 ₸
2331 ₸
```